# img from opener is not img type for canvas drawImage in IE causing TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, type-mismatch

In a.html:

```
<img src="..." id="lexibelle">
<script>
...
var w = window.open("b.html");
...
</script>
```

In b.html:

```
<canvas id="cv" ...></canvas>
<script>
...
var img=window.opener.document.getElementById("lexibelle");
var c=document.getElementById("cv");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
...
</script>
```

Run codes in all browsers well except IE>"<. IE gives ***SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR*** error. I dump img's src, width, height, id properties, so I am sure it points to the same image object in a.html.

I'd like to know if there's a way to use img in ctx.drawImage? Does IE regard img from opener as some other type due to security issue?

Comment: Are you giving the html img element time to fully load? Browsers load images asynchronously and they may not be fully loaded by the time your `drawImage` executes.

Comment: @markE: I believe I did. After opening b.html, I wait for a while to click the button. The error still happens! I just find img and temp_img are of different types and I've modified my question to add this discovery.

Comment: Same problem is happening in Edge, and the workaround doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Actually, I figured the solution. I was creating an off-screen image, and the solution was to just create it from the document of the window containing the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many efforts, I find a workaround:

```
var tmpimg = new Image()
tmpimg.src = img.src;
tmpimg.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
}
```

However, this workaround generates another image object. I use IE debugger to watch values and find that temp_img and img are of different types: temp_img is [HTMLImageElement] type, whereas img becomes [DispHTMLImg] type.